# login is not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

login is working when I have index.php file, but after removing it from Codeigniter it's not working anymore.

login_view.php

```
        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

         <!-- <form class="form-signin" >   -->
          <?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading"> Inventory Management System </h2>
                <div class="login-wrap">

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User ID" id="username" name="username" autofocus required>

                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password" required>

                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-login btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>

                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your model. Code below, is an example of Model file.

```
<?php
Class User extends CI_Model{
function login($username, $password){
$this -> db -> select('id, username, password');
$this -> db -> from('users');
$this -> db -> where('username', $username);
$this -> db -> where('password', MD5($password));
$this -> db -> limit(1);
$query = $this -> db -> get();
if($query -> num_rows() == 1){
return $query->result();
}else{
return false;
}
}
}
?>
```

This should help I guess.

Comment: its working fine .i have issue with url when i click on submit button error 404 come

Comment: it is not redirecting to verifylogin.php

Comment: The requested URL /ci/VerifyLogin was not found on this server.

Comment: There is naming convention in CodeIgniter for the file names. Your controller, model and view files should start with capital letter and all rest small ones. For e.g. Controller_login.php is the right way whereas, Controller_Login.php is not. Similar goes with model and view files.

Comment: Kindly, rename your file to Verifylogin.php or Verify_login.php and check it.

Comment: my htaccess file is in application folder

Comment: <?php echo form_open('Verify_login'); ?>

Comment: Do you have ci folder in your View folder?

Comment: Please tell me what are your controller and model file names.

Comment: Is Verify_login controller or view file?

Comment: in wamp5  www/ci/ application/controller/Verifylogin.php

Comment: Controller -> Login.php and Verifylogin.php

Comment: When you open a form using "<?php echo form_open(); ?>", you should mention your controller file and not your view file.

Comment: i'll mention controller file name

Comment: Please refer this link  [http://www.iluv2code.com/login-with-codeigniter-php.html ] .

Comment: already but the problem is that when i remove index.php file its not working

Comment: Have you tried the same code mentioned in the link. If yes, then I suggest you to download latest CodeIgniter framework from this link https://www.codeigniter.com/download and try again.

Comment: actually when i clean my route path by removing index file its not working

Comment: Where you have kept your .htaccess file?

Comment: which one Code Igniter 3.0 or 2.x

Comment: in my application folder

Comment: Also keep $config['index_page'] = ''; in your config file.

Comment: here is my htaccess file

Comment: RewriteEngine On
 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

Comment: CodeIgniter-3.0.3.zip download this one.

Comment: Keep .htacess file outside application folder, that is, in project folder. 

.htaccess file->
 
'<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>'

Comment: Paste above .htaccess file code without the quotes as it is and keep file outside the application folder and nowhere else.

Comment: can you plz send htaccess file code in another comment

Comment: I will send as another answer give me a moment please.

Comment: Internal Server Error come

Comment: Did you found the .htaccess file?

Comment: my code is working fine but url look ambigious like this http://localhost:81/ci/index.php/user

Comment: i dont want index.php in url

Comment: @SaqibMurtaza What platform are you using? Windows or Linux?

Comment: In Windows it is easily possible to remove index.php from URL but, that's not the case with Linux. I have tried same in Windows and Linux too but, in Linux it didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this .htacess file below --

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```